# In multiple selected data, how do you ask for the delete confirmation - Python, Django, HTML?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to select certain data and delete it from a code that has a check box. I can remove it, but I am unable to request a message of confirmation.

Here is my view.py code.

```
def expens(request):
    data = ''
    number = ''

    if 'delete_all' in request.POST:
        choosen = request.POST.getlist('x[]')
        if choosen:
            for selected in choosen:
                picked = Expenses.objects.filter(id=selected)
                picked.delete()
            messages.info(
                request, "Expens data has been deleted successfully.", extra_tags='success')
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Please select to delete.",
                          extra_tags='error')

    if 'save' in request.POST:
    return render(request, 'expens.html', {'data': data, 'number': number})
```

And my HTML code:

```
{% for expens in picked %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    Do you want to delete: <b>{{ expens.assignment }} {{ expens.amount }}</b>?<br>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'expens_delete_config' expens.id %}">Yes</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'expens' %}">No</a><br>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table class="table table-success table-striped" id="table">

    <thead>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Assignments</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="delete_all">Delete selected</button></th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      {% for info in data %}
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="x[]" value="{{info.id}}"> {{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td>{{info.assignment}}</td>
        <td>{{info.amount}}</td>
        <td>{{info.add_date}}</td>
        <td>
          <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{% url 'expens_delete' info.id %}"><i class="bi bi-x"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{% url 'expens_edit' info.id %}"><i class="bi bi-pencil"></i></a>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to ask for user confirmation about deleting selected data. If yes, delete it; if no, cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a confirm popup, which will ask if user is ready to perform an action.

In this case, you should use [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) or you can make your own native modal with your styles and other stuff.

[confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) should be added to your html script (in its 'js part') and you will be able to submit form only if user presses "OK"

```
if (confirm("Do you want to delete?")) {
  document.getElementById('your_form_id').submit();
}
```